# How can I have OnCompleteListener wait in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I call the `getFavorite` method to get data from the Database Class in Activity. But It doesn't wait for `onCompleteListener`. So The list comes as empty. What should I do?

**GetMovieActivity.java**

```
    private fun getPhotoListFromApi() {
    val apiService = ApiClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService::class.java)

    var list = ArrayList<MovieDetailsResponse>()
    var db = Database()
    db.getFavorite()

    for (id in db.moviesID)
    {
        apiService.getMovieDetails(
                id.toString().toInt(),
                "922df43f1a304aca901feb9728b01943",
                Locale.getDefault().language + "-" + Locale.getDefault().country)
                .enqueue(object : Callback<MovieDetailsResponse> {

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<MovieDetailsResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<MovieDetailsResponse>, response: Response<MovieDetailsResponse>) {
                        response.body()?.let { it ->

                            list.add(it)
                        }

                    }

                })

    }
    adapter.setList((list as List<MovieListItem>?)!!)

}
```

**Database.kt**

```
    fun getFavorite()
{
   val dr = db.collection("Favorites").document(mAuth!!.uid) as DocumentReference
    dr.get().addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<DocumentSnapshot> ->
        if(task.isSuccessful)
        {
            moviesMap = task.result.data!!
            moviesID = moviesMap.get("movies") as ArrayList<Any>
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202)** out.

Comment: I still get list as empty :/

Comment: Should work, it waits for the data isn't that what you want?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I could do now

Answer (score 0):

In you'r adapter you need to snd the new list always and refresh your adapter by calling notifyDataSetChange()
and in once the callback finish you can ether you use liveData to post data to it and listen to it and push the new data to the adapter and refresh it to make sure you always having the right and latest data and you can use rxJava to make sure you're working in background thread and once it finish push it to ui thread and update you'r adapter