# Method always returns false from Firestore DB query

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a method that checks if a list contains a user or not. For some reason it always returns false, even though the user is in the list. The function does work, I know it does find the user, just not sure why it doesn't return anything else but `false`.

I know it works because I have another method with this code snippet in to check if the user is in the list and remove or add them. That works so I know it is pulling the list.

Method:

```
fun checkUserChatChannel(channelId: String): Boolean {
    var list = mutableListOf<String>()
    val currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    var bool = false
    chatChannelsCollectionRef.document(channelId).get().addOnSuccessListener {
        if (it.exists()) {
            list = it.get("userIds") as MutableList<String>
            if(list.contains(currentUserId)){
                bool = true
            }
        }
    }
    return bool
}
```

Calling:

```
boolean inOut = FirestoreUtil.INSTANCE.checkUserChatChannel(moduleId);
if(!inOut)
{
    JLChat.setText("Join");
}
else
{
    JLChat.setText("Leave");
}
```

But the button will always remain on "Join":

This is the other method that I use so I know the code works to remove a user from the list(Nothing to do with question):

```
fun LeaveGroup(channelId: String) {
    currentUserDocRef.collection("engagedChatChannels").document(channelId)
            .delete()
    var list = mutableListOf<String>()
    val currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    chatChannelsCollectionRef.document(channelId).get().addOnSuccessListener {
        if (it.exists()) {
            list = it.get("userIds") as MutableList<String>
            if(list.contains(currentUserId)){
                list.remove(currentUserId)
            }
        }
        val newChannel = chatChannelsCollectionRef.document(channelId)
        newChannel.set(GChatChannel(channelId,list))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase APIs are `asynchronous`, meaning that `onSucces()` function returns immediately after it's invoked, and the callback from the `Task` it returns, will be called some time later. There are no guarantees about how long it will take. So it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available. Because that method returns immediately, the value of your `bool` variable you're trying to return, will not have been populated from the callback yet.

Basically, you're trying to return a value synchronously from an API that's asynchronous. That's not a good idea. You should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended.

A quick solve for this problem would be to use the value of your `bool` variable **only** inside the callback. This also means that you need to change your `checkUserChatChannel` instead of returning a boolean to return void, otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback.