# Solution using onDataChange to Verify Value (Firebase Database & Firebase Auth)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to verify authentication using the role of the user, so I set a Boolean to check whether the user's role is a "trainer" or a "trainee". But `onDataChange` changes the Boolean value only after the intent...

```
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase
private lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
var trainer:Boolean = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("users")

    backRegister.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener {
        val email = etEmail.text.toString()
        val pass = etPass.text.toString()
        login(email, pass)
    }
}

fun login(email:String, pass:String){
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val user = auth.currentUser
                if (user != null) {
                    checkRole(user)
                    if(trainer){
                        intent = Intent(this, HomeTrainer::class.java)
                        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Welcome Trainer",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                    else {
                        var intent = Intent(this, Home::class.java)
                        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Welcome Trainee",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Login Failed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
}

fun checkRole(user:FirebaseUser){
    val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (datas in dataSnapshot.children) {
                if (datas.key.toString() == user.uid) {
                    trainer = false
                    if (datas.child("role").getValue().toString().trim().equals("trainer")) {
                        trainer = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        }
    }
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(postListener)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase APIs are `asynchronous`, meaning that `onDataChange()` function returns immediately after it's invoked, and the callback from the task it returns, will be called some time later. There are no guarantees about how long it will take. So it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available. Because that method returns immediately, the value of your `trainer` variable you're trying to use, will not have been populated from the callback yet. So simply creating it as a global variable won't help and the value it will always be `false`.

Basically, you're trying to use a value synchronously from an API that's asynchronous. That's not a good idea. You should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended.

A quick solve for this problem would be to use the value of your `bool` variable **only** inside the callback, otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback.