# Kotlin/Firebase get list of objects

Tags: list, firebase, kotlin

How can I get a list of objects from **Realtime Database**?

I'm trying to get a list to objects to send the list to my adapted and print the list, so I would like to get the List.

So fat what I have done is the below code:

```
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(snapshotError: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val children = snapshot!!.children
            children.forEach {
                println(it.toString()) // its working.
            }
        }
    })
```

My class:

```
data class MyClass(val name: String, val description: String, val fromDate: Long, val toDate: Long)
```

I have no idea how to set a List list in the **onDataChange**. I guess should be something like the below code but not sure if is the best way:

```
private val list : MutableList<MyClass> = mutableListOf()
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(snapshotError: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("not implemented") 
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (objSnapshot in snapshot.getChildren()) {
                val myClass= objSnapshot .getValue(MyClass::class.java)
                list.add(myClass!!)
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: If your list is empty outside the `onDataChange()` function, please check my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202)** to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda as callback to be notified when data is retrieved, for example:

```
fun loadList(callback: (list: List<MyClass>) -> Unit) {
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(snapshotError: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("not implemented") 
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val list : MutableList<MyClass> = mutableListOf()
            val children = snapshot!!.children
            children.forEach {
                list.add(it.getValue(MyClass::class.java))
            }
            callback(list)
        }
    })
}
```

When you call that function you can specify the lambda at the end to be notified when the list is loaded:

```
loadList {
    // `it` contains the list
}
```