# Get the returned list from firestore based on condition when a value is passed to firestore function

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to return a list from inside firestore function based on if a condition is true.I want to return different lists when different categories are selected.

I tried:

1. putting the return statement out of firestore function which did not work and returned empty list due to firestore async behaviour.
2. creating my own callback to wait for Firestore to return the data using interface as I saw in some other questions but in that case how am i supposed to access it as my function has a Int value(i.e.`private fun getRandomPeople(num: Int): List<String>`)?

What could be the way of returning different lists for different categories based on firestore conditions?

My code(Non Activity class):

```
class Board// Create new game
(private val context: Context, private val board: GridLayout) {
  fun newBoard(size: Int) {
          val squares = size * size
          val people = getRandomPeople(squares)
          createBoard(context, board, size, people)

      }

  fun createBoard(context: Context, board: GridLayout, size: Int, people: List<String>) {
          destroyBoard()
          board.columnCount = size
          board.rowCount = size
          var iterator = 0
          for(col in 1..size) {
              for (row in 1..size) {
                  cell = RelativeLayout(context)
                  val cellSpec = { GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f) }
                  val params = GridLayout.LayoutParams(cellSpec(), cellSpec())
                  params.width = 0
                  cell.layoutParams = params
                  cell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bordered_rectangle)
                  cell.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                  cell.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0)
                  text = TextView(context)
                  text.text = people[iterator++]
                  words.add(text.text as String)
                  text.maxLines = 5
                  text.setSingleLine(false)
                  text.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                  text.setTextColor(0xFF000000.toInt())
                  cell.addView(text)
                  board.addView(cell)
                  cells.add(GameCell(cell, text, false, row, col) {  })
              }
          }
      }

      private fun getRandomPeople(num: Int): List<String> {
          val mFirestore: FirebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
          val mAuth: FirebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
          val currentUser: FirebaseUser=mAuth.currentUser!!
          var validIndexes :MutableList<Int>
          var chosenIndexes = mutableListOf<Int>()
          var randomPeople = mutableListOf<String>()
                 mFirestore.collection("Names").document(gName).get().addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>(){ queryDocumentSnapshot->
                      var categorySelected:String=""

                      if (queryDocumentSnapshot.exists()) {
                          categorySelected= queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("selectedCategory")!!
                          print("categoryselected is:$categorySelected")
                          Toast.makeText(context, "Got sel category from gameroom:$categorySelected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                          when(categorySelected){
                              "CardWords"->{
                                  for (i in 1..num) {
                                      validIndexes=(0..CardWords.squares.lastIndex).toMutableList()
                                      val validIndexIndex = (0..validIndexes.lastIndex).random()
                                      val peopleIndex = validIndexes[validIndexIndex]
                                      chosenIndexes.add(peopleIndex)
                                      val person = CardWords.squares[peopleIndex]
                                      randomPeople.add(person)
                                      validIndexes.remove(peopleIndex)
                                      peopleIndexes = chosenIndexes.toList()
                                  }
                              }
                              else->{}
                          }
                      }
                      else {
                          Toast.makeText(context, "Sel category does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                      }

                  }).addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener { e->
                      val error=e.message
                      Toast.makeText(context,"Error:"+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                  })

      return randomPeople.toList()

      }
}
```

Activity A:

```
Board(this, gridLay!!)
```

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202)** out.

Comment: i did check that out but in that case when readdata is accessed readdata does not have a value in the function,in my case i got a value in function which is passed to another function so Im not sure how to do it(i.e. val people = getRandomPeople(squares)
        createBoard(context, board, size, people))...if i do  val people = getRandomPeople(squares,getrandompeople(object: MyCallback {
    override fun onCallback(value: List<String>) {
        Log.d("TAG", list.size.toString())
    })
        createBoard(context, board, size, people),then people variable will no longer be a List<String>

Comment: @Alex Mamo This is working for me now,but I am not sure if its the right way.I got the firestore value and passed in in intent in previous activity.Then I passed that intent I got from prev activity in sharedpreference as value in my activity and then i used sharedpreference  to get that value in my non activity class.