# Use of Either<L,R> with Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, either

I'm trying to use Either with Firestore , the function I have is this one

```
fun setDataIntoFirestore(data: HashMap<String,Any>): Either<Failure,Boolean>{
         db.collection("test")
            .add(data)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                //Here I need Either.Right(true);
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("FirestoreData", "Failure: " + it.message)
                //Here I want to add Either.Left(it)
            }
    }
```

I'm trying to do this because I want to notify my view when the data has been added to the database, but when I mark the function to return Either I need to return that type and I cant return anything inside the Task that is suggesting me.

Any ideas on how to implement this ?

I'm calling this method from my use case like this

```
class SendProductUseCase: UseCase<Boolean, HashMap<String, Any>>() {

    private val repo = SendProductRepo()

    override suspend fun run(params: HashMap<String, Any>): Either<Failure, Boolean> {
        return repo.setDataIntoFirestore(params)
    }

}
```

And UseCase is a generic UseCase for each one

```
abstract class UseCase<out Type, in Params> where Type : Any {

    abstract suspend fun run(params: Params): Either<Failure, Type>

    operator fun invoke(params: Params, onResult: (Either<Failure, Type>) -> Unit = {}) {
        val job = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) { run(params) }
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { onResult(job.await()) }
    }

    class None
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use interface to make it return what you want OR I'd prefer to send Higher order function and use it where you want.

your code will be something like this

```
  fun setDataIntoFirestore(data: HashMap<String,Any> , retValue : (Either<Failure,Boolean>) -> (Unit)){
    db.collection("test")
        .add(data)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            retValue.invoke(Either.Right(true))
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.d("FirestoreData", "Failure: " + it.message)
            //Here I want to add Either.Left(it)
        }
}
```

you may find complication error but this to demonstrate my idea

Comment: Does I need to still return Either<L,R> in this function ? Because If its a high order function and I use fun setData(....): Either<Failure,Boolean> Its saying the same error , that I need to return something from the method

Comment: you won't need the return as your function is being called when the db finishes and by the way the reason you can't return is that db call is being called asynchronously.

Comment: Adding, this retValue requires me to pass an Either from the second function in my question, but I dont need to pass that since I'm returning an either at that function, how can we fix this ?

Comment: You won't need to return from this function also, any return will be converted to this function, this function will be delegated

Comment: I get that, the only thing is that at my second code block where I'm calling the high order function, now needs to pass an either as a parameter, and I dont need to do that since I just need the value of either within the method that is calling

Comment: you can do it internally as you need this either to inform you that the dc call done successfully,right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199315/discussion-between-coffeebreak-and-sayed-el-abady).

Answer (score 1):

Both `onScuccess()` and `onFailure()` methods are asynchronous meaning that each one of them will fire only when the data is committed to, or rejected by the Firebase servers. So it will take some time so one or the other method will be triggered and there are no guarantees about how long it will take. Depending on your connection speed and the state, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds even to a few seconds. So there is no way you can return an object of type `Either<Failure,Boolean>` as result of a method. To solve this, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback.

P.S. There is an excelent video where Doug Stevenson explains in practic, how you can achieve this using `LiveData`:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fu2K3lOU3N0

Comment: Thanks Alex, I knew about the interface callback method, but I wanted to give a try at Either with more of a functional programming perspective

Comment: See Doug's video. You'll understand for sure what I mean. Keep me posted me if it works.