# After Log.d(TAG, "downloadImgsUriArrayList:$downloadImagesUriList ") upload codes excute before for iterator's .addOnCompleteListener

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage

After `Log.d(TAG, "downloadImgsUriArrayList:$downloadImagesUriList ")` upload codes excute before for iterator's .addOnCompleteListener lead to `var downloadImagesUriList: MutableList<String>  = mutableListOf()` is empty.

How to solve this problem?

```
var downloadImagesUriList: MutableList<String>  = mutableListOf()

//Upload images button
upload_imgs_button.setOnClickListener {
    Log.d(TAG, "uploadImgsPath: $uploadImgsPath");
        //Upload images to firebase storage
    if (uploadImgsPath != null) {

        for (uriForUpload in imagesList) {
            val imgNameUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            val withAppendedPath =
                Uri.withAppendedPath(uriForUpload, imgNameUUID).toString()
            var imgFileRef = uploadImgsPath!!.child(withAppendedPath)
            imgFileRef.putFile(uriForUpload)
                .continueWithTask {
                    if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                        it.exception?.let {
                            throw it
                        }
                    }
                    imgFileRef.downloadUrl
                }.addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        var uriForDownload = it.result.toString()
                        Log.d(TAG, "uriForDownload:$uriForDownload ");
                        downloadImagesUriList.add(uriForDownload)
                    }
                }

        }

//The process will run here before downloadImagesUriList.add(uriForDownload) was excuted.
//How to solve this problem?
        Log.d(TAG, "downloadImgsUriArrayList:$downloadImagesUriList ");
        var uploadedImages = UploadedImages(
            categoryDesignID, user!!.uid,
            downloadImagesUriList, Timestamp.now()
        )
        //Save uploaded images path info to firestore
        firestore.collection("uploadedImages").add(uploadedImages)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Please choose a category",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

Comment: Firebase APIs are asynchronous, so you can check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202)** out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase APIs, like most modern cloud APIs, are asynchronous, since they interact with a (potentially time-consuming) server. Instead of blocking your main thread while the cloud interaction happens, the clients allow your main code to continue, and then call back once the cloud API has completed its work.

In your code that means that the `Log.d(TAG, "downloadImgsUriArrayList:$downloadImagesUriList ");` runs **before** the `imgFileRef.downloadUrl`. This explains why nothing is written to the database by `add(uploadedImages)`: the download URLs haven't been determined yet, because the upload is still in progress.

To solve this problem, all code that requires the download URL of an upload, must be **inside** the completion listener of that upload.

The simplest way to do this, is to add a new URL each time the upload of that file completes:

```
for (uriForUpload in imagesList) {
    val imgNameUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    val withAppendedPath =
        Uri.withAppendedPath(uriForUpload, imgNameUUID).toString()
    var imgFileRef = uploadImgsPath!!.child(withAppendedPath)
    imgFileRef.putFile(uriForUpload)
        .continueWithTask {
            if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                it.exception?.let {
                    throw it
                }
            }
            imgFileRef.downloadUrl
        }.addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                var uriForDownload = it.result.toString()
                Log.d(TAG, "uriForDownload:$uriForDownload ");
                downloadImagesUriList.add(uriForDownload)

                Log.d(TAG, "downloadImgsUriArrayList:$downloadImagesUriList ");
                var uploadedImages = UploadedImages(
                    categoryDesignID, user!!.uid,
                    downloadImagesUriList, Timestamp.now()
                )
                //Save uploaded images path info to firestore
                firestore.collection("uploadedImages").add(uploadedImages)
            }
        }
}
```

The above will create a new document each time an upload completes. You'll *either* want to update the same document after each file completes *or* wait until the last file has uploaded before creating the document. There are many ways to do either, but a simple way is to simply keep a counter of how many files have completed uploading:

```
var uploadedCount = 0
for (uriForUpload in imagesList) {
    ...

        }.addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                var uriForDownload = it.result.toString()
                Log.d(TAG, "uriForDownload:$uriForDownload ");
                downloadImagesUriList.add(uriForDownload)
                if (uploadedCount++ >= imagesList.size) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "downloadImgsUriArrayList:$downloadImagesUriList ");
                    var uploadedImages = UploadedImages(
                        categoryDesignID, user!!.uid,
                        downloadImagesUriList, Timestamp.now()
                    )
                    //Save uploaded images path info to firestore
                    firestore.collection("uploadedImages").add(uploadedImages)
                }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Frank van Puffelen:
Your solution actually solved my problem. Thank you very much. ^_^