# How to use continues instead of bad callbacks

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I get data from Firestone , Because  do not want empty list to be return ,I use callbacks 
 is coroutine better , I have a lot of this so call back is noisy for this case , is async/await will be a good solution

```
         getHerosFromCloud(object :OnFinishedCallbacks {
             override fun onFinshed(list: List<Any>) {
                 CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                     MainDatabase.heroDao.insertAll(*(list as List<Hero>).toTypedArray())

                 }
             }
         })


interface OnFinishedCallbacks {
    fun onFinshed( list:List<Any>)
}


 fun getHerosFromCloud(onFinishedCallbacks: OnFinishedCallbacks)
        {

            val heroList =ArrayList<Hero>()

                   db.collection("Heros")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot  ->
                    if (documentSnapshot  != null) {
                        for(heroDoc in documentSnapshot) {
                            heroList.add(heroDoc.toObject(Hero::class.java))
                        }

                        Log.d("newherosNames", "newdoorsNames data: ${heroList}")
                        onFinishedCallbacks.onFinshed(heroList)
                    } else {
                        Log.d("heros", "No such document")
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Log.d("heros", "get failed with ", exception)
                }

        }
```

Comment: You can check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51595202/5246885)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59124705/5246885)** out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to make your code more clean and consistent when using callback Api. You can use [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/suspend-coroutine.html) or [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html).

`suspendCoroutine` suspends coroutine in which it executed until we decide to continue by calling appropriate methods - `Continuation.resume...`.

`suspendCancellableCoroutine` function, it behaves similar to `suspendCoroutine` with additional feature - provides an implementation of `CancellableContinuation` to the block.

For your example it will look something like this:

```
suspend fun getHeroesFromCloud() = suspendCoroutine<List<Hero>> { continuation ->
    db.collection("Heros")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot  ->
            val heroList = ArrayList<Hero>()
            if (documentSnapshot  != null) {

                for(heroDoc in documentSnapshot) {
                    heroList.add(heroDoc.toObject(Hero::class.java))
                }

                Log.d("newherosNames", "newdoorsNames data: ${heroList}")
            } else {
                Log.d("heros", "No such document")
            }
            continuation.resume(heroList)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
            Log.d("heros", "get failed with ", exception)
        }

}

// Call this function from a coroutine
suspend fun someFun() {
    val heroes = getHeroesFromCloud()
    // use heroes
}
```

Comment: Can also use `kotlinx-coroutines-play-services` to not have to rewrite this.