# I want to use setter in kotlin to set value of document snapshot

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I try to use setter in kotlin but can't set the document snapshot data

```
    private lateinit var document: QueryDocumentSnapshot
//intialize top
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                        for (document in documents) {
                            klog.d("#fail", document.get("question").toString())
                            setDocument(document)
                        }
                    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                        klog.d("#fail", exception.message)
                    }
        }
    }

    fun setDocument(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
        this.document=document
    }
```

Comment: I'm new to kotlin any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: When I'm using the document variable,it's say it's not initialised

Comment: If you know anything please help me out , @Peter Haddad

Comment: Why would you do something like this `this.document=document`?

Comment: how should I set the data then @AlexMamo, I used to set data in java this way.

Comment: please _ /\ _  help me out.

Comment: I just want to set the document snapshot data value I'm fetching into a separate variable.so, I can use it whenever needed in the class.

Comment: You cannot simply assign that variable in the way you do and use wherever you want. Please check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51595202/5246885)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59124705/5246885)** out.

Comment: can you please copy-paste the 2nd ans so I can ask some question @AlexMamo

Comment: Copy paste what?

Comment: your 2nd answer where you explain how to use coroutines to pass list

Comment: @subratasharma It's already explained there. That's why I pointed that out in a comment.

Comment: but I can't call **suspend method** from my activity class @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

try the following code, to check if the varialbe is initialised

```
        if (::document.isInitialized){
            //variable is initialised
        }
```

Comment: no my problem is to setting the data in the document field

Comment: basically you are trying to use the variable, before the value is set from firbase, i would suggest, read the variable after you have set the value (after the callback in successlistener) or check if variable is initialised, i'm editing the answer above, to check if the variable is intialised