# Kotlin - Best way to update Android Views using retrieved Firebase data

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update my Android views using some data that I've got on a Firebase Realtime DB. Since I'm using Kotlin, I've encountered some problems doing this simple thing. I'm not an expert on Realtime DB, I've just discovered that the calls to the DB are made asynchronously, and this means I've got to use the data inside the *onDataChange* function.
I also discovered that Kotlin doesn't let me change the value of a View that I passed as a parameter to some function (like the one I created to update that View using the data retrieved from the DB). So I'm counting on you for this.

What's the best way to retrieve data from Firebase and use that data to update my Views? I would like to have some clean code, like different functions that do the right thing, without having a pile of code in the onCreate method of my MainActivity.

Comment: Have you ever heard of design patterns?

Comment: I know what they are, but as I said I'm not an expert and I don't really know how to use them in practice. That's why I asked here, to get an example, even the simplest, to adapt my code and make it work

Comment: You can use the example they have in the official patterns documentation. There is a ton of articles with examples using design patterns with async data fetch. In eg if I search for "firebase firestore mvvm" I get a ton of results

Comment: Alright I'll take a look at those, thank you! But a specific example of Kotlin + Firebase Realtime DB pattern would help me a lot more

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51595202/5246885)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59124705/5246885)** out.

Comment: @AlexMamo thank you very much, the explanations were really clear!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
fun fetchFeed(): LiveData<List<Feed>> {
  val result: MutableLiveData<List<Feed>> = MutableLiveData()
  firestore.collection("feeds")
    .addSnapshotListener { collectionSnapshot, exception ->
      if (exception != null) {
          //...handle error
          return@addSnapshotListener
      }
      if (collectionSnapshot == null || collectionSnapshot.isEmpty) {
          //...no data or no collection
        return@addSnapshotListener
      }
      val value: MutableList<Feed> = arrayListOf()
      collectionSnapshot.documents.map {
        value.add(it.toObject(Feed::class.java))
      }
      data.postValue(value)
    }
    return result
}


class FeedFragmentViewModel: ViewModel() {
  //ApiService is a singleton or an DAO eg... where your fetchFeed is declared or have access to it
  val result: LiveData<List<Feed>> = ApiService.fetchFeed()
}

class FeedFragment: Fragment() {

  override onActivityCreated() {
    //initialize view model -> in docs
    viewModel.result.observe(this, Observer {
      myListAdapter.updateList(it)
    })
  }
}
```

It is not a complete solution but along these lines I think you should be able to incorporate realtimedb in it. Long story short you want to observe live data which represents the data from realtime db. When ever those c hange your callback in observer gets called where you can update the UI accordingly

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your patience, this will help me a lot!

Comment: @Sosnos if you have any more questions just edit your answer and let me know in the comment and I'll try to help you out