# How to retrieve data from Firestore and store it in global variable

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I can't seem to figure out how to store the data that I retrieve from Firestore in a global variable of  type custom object. I am able to print out the data from within the `.addOnSuccessListener` but I can't assign the data to a global variable.

My code is as follows:

```
 override fun getData(documentPath: String): ShopModel {
        var shopModel = ShopModel()
        firestore.firestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().build()
        val document = firestore.collection("shops").document(documentPath)
        document.get().addOnSuccessListener {
            shopModel = it.toObject(ShopModel::class.java)!!
            info(shopModel) //this prints the model out and it works
        }
        return shopModel //this returns an object with empty fields
    }
```

Comment: get() is asynchronous and returns immediately. The callback you provide is invoked some time later, after the query is complete. Because of this, you won't be able to return the results of the query from the function.  You should instead look into using a LiveData or coroutines to manage this asynchronous behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the value of your global variable inside the callback (`addOnSuccessListener`), you can't return the value inside your function because `get()` works asynchronously hence when you reach `return` the variable `shopModel` has nothing inside it until the callback is executed and by then the function has already *returned* with an empty variable.

This has been explained before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114584/setting-global-variable-with-cloud-firestore-on-kotlin) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/)