# Firebase repository MVVM pattern

Tags: android, firebase, design-patterns

Suppose I have a repository class whose methods are invoked from multiple view models in different fragments and each method of the repository do async Firebase requests using addOnSuccessListener to handle each one. Will the effect of doing this be create a tons of listeners that will run indefinitely? If so, how can I handle this? I can pass the activity instance in the repository and define a lifecycle for them, but what will happen if I will do many requests using that repository?

EDIT1:

My repository exposes methods like the following:

```
fun getTransactionsBySellerID(_sellerID: String): ArrayList<Transaction>? {
        var transactions : ArrayList<Transaction> = ArrayList()

         db.collection(COLLECTION)
            .whereEqualTo("sellerID", _sellerID)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                val trans = it.documents
                transactions?.clear()
                trans.forEach{
                    val transObj = it.toObject(Transaction::class.java)
                    transObj!!.transID = it.id
                    transactions?.add(transObj)
                }
            }



        return transactions
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of the database that you are using? Show the code that you are using for getting data.

Comment: Check my edit please

Comment: There is no way you can return that `` as a result of a method. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59124705/5246885) to how can you solve this using a custom callback/Coroutines.

Comment: I know, I'm not asking how can return a list without using callbacks/coroutines