# Kotlin: How to fetch data from firebase synchronously?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I was wondering if there is any way to fetch data from the firebase synchronously. What i mean by that, i have to always attach a `tasks.await(task)` to wait for the firebase data to fetch, if i will not do, my data will not be fetched the function will be executed. But, in order to do that, I have to always attach a `Thread { /* Code */ }.Start()` . However, if I attach a thread there, The code will run asynchronously and that will again create problems if i want to run the code synchronously. So, i was wondering if there is any way to fetch the data from Firebase synchronously in Kotlin.

Comment: On Android: Fetching data and using network connections should always be doneasynchronously on another thread. Otherwise your UI will block any interaction, until  the response returns, which could take some time and freezes the screen.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can fetch the data first and then run the rest of the code without using the await and threads

Comment: Why don't you try rxjava?

Comment: You can also try to use Kotlin Coroutines which lets you write Asynchronous non-blocking code.

Comment: As Simulant pointed out in his comment, trying to get the data synchronously is not a good option to go ahead with. As Gil Becker mentioned in his comment, using [Kotlin Coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59124705/5246885), might help you solve this issue.