# How to return the user after finishing the network request?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

in this method I wanted to get the user's list after finishing the request not immediately because it is giving 0 user's list from Firebase?
Why run blocking  coroutine is not working here?

```
   fun getAllFollowingsLists(uid: String): List<User> {
        val users = mutableListOf<User>()
        val collection = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users")
            .document(uid).collection("followings")

        runBlocking {
            collection.get().addOnCompleteListener {
                for (k in it.result!!) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "getAllFollowingsLists: ${k.toObject(User::class.java)} ")
                    users.add(k.toObject(User::class.java))
                }
            }
        }
        return users
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin) ?

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But why runBlocking is not working here? it should suspend the thread

Answer (score 2):

Because `addOnCompleteListener` is not blocking, it finished without waiting for `get()` to finish. Instead it put a listener which will run when `get()` finishes.

`addOnCompleteListener` is not async, so the `runBlocking` is useless here.

You should do whatever you want to do with the `List<User>` after the for loop in the listener.