# Is there any way to return value and end a function in callback?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am struggling with Firestore.

```
    suspend fun writeClientMemo(userId: String, memo: Memo): MemoWriteResponse {
        val response = MemoWriteResponse()

        val docRef = Firebase.firestore
            .collection(COLLECTION_USER)
            .document(userId)

        val result = Tasks.await(docRef.get())
        
        if (result.exists() && result.data != null) {
            Log.d("memo", "data exists ")

            val res = docRef.update(FIELD_MEMO_LIST, FieldValue.arrayUnion(memo))

            res.addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("memo", "success")

                response.isSuccessful = true

                // What I want to do is something like these:
                // 1. return@addOnSuccessListener response
                // 2. return response
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.d("memo", "failed")
                
                response.isSuccessful = false
                response.errorMessage = "${e.toString}"
            }
        }

        return response // At the moment this always get false(default is false)
    }
```

I tried to make this synchronous but didn't work.

```
when {
    res.isSuccessful -> {
        response.isSuccessful = true
        Log.d("memo", "true: ${response.toString()}")
    }
    res.isCanceled -> {
        response.run {
            isSuccessful = false
            errorMessage = "ADD: Error writing document}"
        }    
        Log.d("memo", "false: ${response.toString()}")
    }
    res.isComplete -> {
        Log.d("memo", "false2: ${response.toString()}")
    }
    else->{
        Log.d("memo", "false3: ${response.toString()}")
    }
}
```

I always get false3 here.

Comment: You would have to use a callback. Google kotlin callbacks or something along those lines.

Comment: To solve this, you can check this answer, [How to return a list from Firestore database as a result of a function in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202) or this article, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried it and didn't work. It seems like the function ends before get the result. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to return value and end a function in a callback?

No, you cannot simply return a value of an asynchronous operation as a result of a method. Firebase API, as most modern cloud/ APIs are asynchronous. This means that it takes some time until the operation completes. Since you are using the Kotlin programming language, I recommend you consider using [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) and call `.await()` like this:

```
docRef.get().await();
```

This means that you suspend the operation until the data is available. This means that this value can be returned as a result of a method.

For more information you can check my answers from the following post:

- [How to return a list from Firestore database as a result of a function in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202)

Or read the following article:

- [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953)

Where I have explained four ways in which you can deal with the Firestore using get().

P.S.

> I tried to make this synchronous but didn't work

Never try to do that. It's best to get used to dealing with Firestore in such a way. Hopefully, my explanation from the above answer and article can help you a little bit.

Comment: docRef .get() doesn't have await() function.

Comment: It certainly has if you add the [corresponding dependencies](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) in your Gradle file. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Sorry, It haven't solve my problem. Now, I am using public repo for now.

Comment: "It haven't solve my problem" doesn't provide enough information to further help you. What exactly did you do and didn't work the way you expected? Have added the correct dependencies? Could you call await()? Please provide more information.

Comment: Any new information?

Comment: I use coroutine and I can't use `await()` after `docRef.get()`.  And I am still trying to figure out, please ignore a comment above, I thought it was another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `suspendCoroutine()` utility function. It is a common practice to use it to convert asynchronous callback-based API to synchronous suspend API. You use it like this:

```
suspend fun loadSomeData(): String {
    return suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        loadSomeDataAsync(
            onSuccess = {
                cont.resume("ok!")
            },
            onFailure = {
                cont.resume("failed!")
                // OR:
                cont.resume(null)
                // OR:
                cont.resumeWithException(Exception("failed"))
            }
        )
    }
}
```

`suspendCoroutine()` suspends execution in outer scope until one of `resume*()` function is called. Then it resumes with the provided result.