# Is there a way to check a firestore document if its certain field is equivalent to some value?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function where I validate a product as you can see in this snippet:

```
private fun validateProduct() : Boolean{

        val newProductName = binding.etNewProductName.text.toString().trim()
        val newProductPrice = binding.etNewProductPrice.text.toString().trim()
        val newProductCategory = binding.spNewProductCategory.selectedItem.toString()



        return when{
            TextUtils.isEmpty(newProductName) -> {
                showErrorSnackBar(binding.root, "Product name cannot be empty.", true)
                false

            }
            TextUtils.isEmpty(newProductPrice) -> {
                showErrorSnackBar(binding.root, "Price cannot be empty.", true)
                false
            }

            //make sure the first element is not a valid category
            newProductCategory == binding.spNewProductCategory.getItemAtPosition(0) -> {
                showErrorSnackBar(binding.root, "Please select a valid category.", true)
                false
            }

            //check if the new product's name already exists in the Firestore collection.
            //if so, return false.

 


            else -> {
                true
            }

        }
    }
```

Edit:
My logic in mind was to iterate over the documents. Check each document if document["name"].toString() == newProductName if so, return false and display an error snackbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to check a Firestore document if its certain field is equivalent to some value?

Sure, there is. As you already said, yes, you have to iterate over the collection, but **not** for getting all documents and checking the new product name on the client. You have to do that in a query. Assuming that you have a collection called "products", to check if a specific product name already exists, please use the following lines of code:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val productsRef = db.collection("products")
Query queryByProductName = productsRef.whereEqualTo("productName", newProductName)
queryByProductName.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        if (!task.result.isEmpty) {
            Log.d(TAG, "$newProductName already exists.")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "$newProductName doesn't exist.")
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.exception)
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. I guess I have to put this somewhere else? I wanted to put this codeblock unto my validateProduct() function where it simply return a boolean value.

Comment: You [cannot return the result of an asynchronous operation as a result of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51595202/5246885). You have wait of the data and use the logic inside the callback.