# MutableList remaining empty (?) even though i'm populating it

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelist

I'm trying to populate a mutable list so that I can use it for a recycler view. Unfortunately, although (i think) I'm populating the list, it's still remaining empty and the recycler view is not working (and I imagine it's because of the list issue). Please see below for the code:

```
        private val newList: MutableList<NewListModel> = mutableListOf()
        private val oldList = retrieveOldList()

        private fun retrieveAndPopulate() {
                
                for (i in 0 until oldList.size){
        
                    val oldItem = oldList[i]
                    
                    val itemOne = oldItem.itemOne
                    val itemTwo = oldItem.itemTwo
                    val itemThree = oldItem.itemThree
                    val itemFour = oldItem.itemFour
    
                    val newItemData =
                        NewListModel(
                            itemOne, itemTwo, itemThree, itemFour
                        )
    
                newList.add(newItemData)
                Log.d(
                    "RetrieveData",
                    "${newItemData.itemOne} has been added to the list."
                )
            }
        }
```

The class below is for the "NewListModel"

```
@Keep
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class NewListModel (
    var itemOne: String ?= null,
    var itemTwo: String ?= null,
    var itemThree: String ?= null,
    var itemFour: String ?= null,
)
```

Below is how i try to populate the "oldList"

```
fun retrieveData(): MutableList<OldListModel> {

        val list: MutableList<OldListModel> = mutableListOf()
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/storage")

        ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    ref.get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener {

                            for (listItem in snapshot.children) {
                                val listItem = snapshot.getValue(OldListModel::class.java)

                                if (listItem != null) {
                                    list.add(listItem)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                } else {
                    Log.d(
                        "Data",
                        "Retrieving data was unsuccessful."
                    )
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
        return list
}
```

It's probably worth mentioning that I'm getting the data from one mutable list and adding it to another. Any help is much appreciated

(below is how i try to populate the recycler view)

```
val newList = retrieveAndPopulate()

val recyclerView = findViewById<View>(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
val adapterAdapter = AdapterAdapter(newList)
recyclerView.adapter = adapterAdapter
```

Comment: You've declared two `private` fields within a function which is not valid - your code shouldn't even compile. Are you sure old list has items? What happens with newList? Are you actually feeding it to the adapter? Please show a complete, working example.

Comment: @dominicoder that was my bad, i pasted it in the wrong place. Yes, I'm sure the oldList is populated because when i use "Log.d" to print it's contents, i actually get a mutable list with contents. newList doesn't even do anything. The message doesn't even get printed. RE the recycler view, i am feeding it to the adapter

Comment: @dominicoder if it helps, I've added a snippet of the code i use to populate the recycler view.

Comment: `val newList = retrieveAndPopulate()` is invalid since you never return anything from `retrieveAndPopulate()`. If the message doesn't get printed then your old list is empty. Debug your app to determine the point of failure: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: @dominicoder you were right, i have tried to debug the code and realised that the oldList doesn't actually get populated (i thought it was, but i realised i was just printing the snapshot, which gave the impression that it was working). I've added the snippet of code that populates the oldList. Do you know what could possibly be causing the issue? - thanks a lot for the help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that I had was with regards to not using `callbacks` while trying to access data in an `onSuccessListener`. This was causing the list not to be updated at all.

After a day of scrolling on the internet, I finally found these solutions:

1. Solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin)
2. Extension to the solution: [link](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1870064)

This solved my problem and I hope it solves yours too!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you think you're running code sequentially when it's running asynchronously. See the numbered comments from your function to trace the order of execution:

```
fun retrieveData(): MutableList<OldListModel> {

    // 1. Here you create a list
    val list: MutableList<OldListModel> = mutableListOf()
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/storage")

    // 2. Here a listener is added that will let you know LATER when the data is ready
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        // 4. LATER the data changed will get called
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                ref.get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        // 5. EVEN LATER this listener is called with data
                        for (listItem in snapshot.children) {
                            val listItem = snapshot.getValue(OldListModel::class.java)

                            // 6. FINALLY - you add to a list that has long since stopped being relevant
                            if (listItem != null) {
                                list.add(listItem)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            } else {
                Log.d(
                    "Data",
                    "Retrieving data was unsuccessful."
                )
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
    return list // 3. Here you return the EMPTY list that was created
}
```

A solution - though likely not the *best* solution is to update your list once the callbacks complete:

```
private val theList = mutableListOf<YourDataModelType>

fun retrieveData(): { // No longer returning anything

    // Remove this, no longer returning anything
    // val list: MutableList<OldListModel> = mutableListOf()

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/storage")
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                ref.get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        theList.clear() // Clear out existing data

                        for (listItem in snapshot.children) {
                            val listItem = snapshot.getValue(OldListModel::class.java)

                            if (listItem != null) {
                                theList.add(listItem)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        // Since you're using Kotlin, you could use a map,
                        // but that's unrelated to this issue
                        // val list = snapshot.children.map { getValue(...) }.filterNotNull()
                        
                        // Now that we have a full list here, update:
                        updateAdapterWithNewData(theList)
                    }
            } else {
                Log.d(
                    "Data",
                    "Retrieving data was unsuccessful."
                )
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
}
```

Where `updateAdapterWithNewData` is a function you write to do as it says.

Please read up on asynchronous programming and make sure you understand how the code is flowing when using callbacks / listeners in frameworks like Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this resolves the problem, but how do i then go about accessing the data from another class if i remove the return from the "retrieveData" method? I would ideally like to be able to access the list from everywhere within the class (global variable), but I'm struggling to do that as the "retrieveData" method (now) doesn't return anything and the variable that stores the list is localised in the said method.

Comment: Then don't localize it in said method - use a class field instead. See update.

Comment: I've followed the example and although the old one gets populated (definitely), the new list doesn't get updated. Each time i access the variable from within the method, i get the correct value returned, but once i try to access it from outside the method, the list is empty. I'm not sure why

Comment: Probably for the exact same reason as your original problem - you are accessing the data before it is populated. Of course, I can only guess without any code to look at.

Comment: I've followed this example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin). The first answer seems to address the issue I have and my issue has been reolved. Thanks for helping point me in the right direction.