# Сan't get data from Firestore, no errors

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from the Firestore. The code below, mostly taken from the docs doesn't get anything from the database, although writing data works without issue.

Code from fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    init()
}

private fun init() {
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    mFirestoreRef = db.collection("users").document(USER_ID).collection("deals")
    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DealsViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.retriveData(mFirestoreRef)
    recyclerView = binding.rcView
    adapter = TradeNoteAdapter()
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    var notes = viewModel.getAllNotes()
    adapter.setList(notes)
}
```

Code from ViewModel:

```
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference
import space.timur.tradenotefirebase.APP
import space.timur.tradenotefirebase.model.TradeNoteModel

class DealsViewModel : ViewModel() {

private var notes: ArrayList<TradeNoteModel> = ArrayList()

fun retriveData(firestoreReference: CollectionReference){
    firestoreReference.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for(document in documents){
                var note = document.toObject(TradeNoteModel::class.java)
                notes.add(note)
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener{ e->
            Toast.makeText(APP, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}

fun getAllNotes(): ArrayList<TradeNoteModel> {
    return notes
}

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you should deal with Firestore. All Firebase APIs are asynchronous, so there is no way you can simply return `notes`, as a result of a method. To solve this, you can use a custom callback as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51595202/5246885), or since you're using Kotlin, you might also consider using [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html), as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59124705/5246885).

Besides that, I highly recommend you read this article:

- [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953)

Where I have explained four ways in which you can deal with Firestore.

Comment: Thank you. This helped resolve the issue.
I will definitely read this article.