# how to retrive data from firebase realtime database as a list

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an Android project and have a button that inserts data into the Realtime Database child and it's working fine. but now i need to get that data as a list and append it to listof to be able then to display it in a lazyColumn.
here are images from Firebase and Kotlin files

have seen many ways to add data but couldn't find any solution about how to get data as a list.
here is my last code update :
when i click display, my app get crush. could you please check what's missing here

```
fun Greeting() {
val mydb = Firebase.database.reference
var authorText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var contentText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var myList = mutableListOf<Message>()

Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    TextField(value = authorText, onValueChange = {authorText=it})
    TextField(value = contentText, onValueChange = {contentText=it})
    
    Button(onClick = {
        val message = Message(authorText,contentText)
        mydb.child("messages").push().setValue(message) }) {
        Text(text = "insert")
    }
    Button(onClick = {
        val rf = mydb.child("messages")
        rf.get().addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                val snapshot = it.result
                val messages = mutableListOf<Message>()
                for (messageSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val message = messageSnapshot.getValue(Message::class.java)
                    messages.add(message!!)
                }
                myList=messages

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "${it.exception?.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
        
        }) { Text(text = "display")
    }
    LazyColumn {
        items(myList){
            Row {
                Text(text = it.author)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(2.dp))
                Text(text = it.content)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
data class Message(var author:String,var content:String)

Comment: Your question is for Android, iOS, or the web?

Comment: its about android

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you said in the last comment that you're looking for a solution to read the data under the `messages` node on Android, then please check the below solution using Kotlin:

```
val db = Firebase.database.reference
val messagesRef = db.child("messages")
messagesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        val snapshot = it.result
        for (messageSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
            val author = messageSnapshot.getValue(String::class.java)
            val content = messageSnapshot.getValue(String::class.java)
            Log.d(TAG, "$author/$content")
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "${it.exception?.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

So as you can see, you have to create a reference that points to the `messages` node, call `get()`, and then iterate through all children to get the data. However, this solution will work only if the `messages` node is a direct child of your root reference.

Or if you already have a clas called `Message` and you want to create a list of messages, then you can use:

```
val db = Firebase.database.reference
val messagesRef = db.child("messages")
messagesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        val snapshot = it.result
        val messages = mutableListOf<Message>()
        for (messageSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
            val message = messageSnapshot.getValue(Message::class.java)
            messages.add(message!!) //
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "${messages.size}") //
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "${it.exception?.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

The result in your logcat will be:

```
2
```

Comment: I have Uploaded 2 images that show what my data looks like on firebase and an image showing my code on android sturdio. the problem is i need to append data and add it to my emptylist   i already  var myList = mutableListOf(emptyList<Message>())

Comment: Hello Alex, thanks for your help. I appreciate it. I just tried what you mentioned and got red line under message on messages.add(message) . ( type mismatch : inferred type is Message? but Message was expected )

Comment: .and also error under size() on Log.d(TAG, "${messages.size()}")    Expression type of type (Int) can not be envoked as a function.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, my bad. I just wrote the code, not tested it. So please check my updated answer. It should be `messages.add(message!!)` and `"${messages.size}")`. Does it work now?

Comment: i use  mydb.child("messages").push().setValue(message) }) for inserting data to firebase and its working fine , but when i try to retrive from firebase ,the app crushes.

Comment: If the app crashes there is stack trace. Please edit your question and add it so we can see the why it crashes.

Comment: i have added the full code . insert  button is working fine it reflects and update the database without any issue . but display button is crushing the app..

Comment: There is no way you can assign `myList=messages` and use it outside the callback. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202). You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).

Comment: ok, very thanks Alex. I will check and read in details