# How do I retrieve the images which have been stored in the firebase database and show in the recycler view?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am currently working on a project that uses firebase. I have problems concerning using firebase. How do I retrieve the images?

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder.ImageViewHolder> {
    private  Context mContext;
    private List<Model> mModel;

    public ViewHolder(Context context, List<Model> models)
    {
        mContext=context;
        mModel=models;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row, viewGroup,false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder, int i) {
        Model mModelcur = mModel.get(i);
        imageViewHolder.img_description.setText(mModelcur.getDescription());
        Picasso.get().load(mModelcur.getImage()).into(imageViewHolder.image_view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mModel.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView img_description;
        public ImageView image_view;
        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            img_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rDescription);
            image_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rImageview);
        }
    }  
}
```

The code above shows the viewholder while this code is for executing the firebase with the viewholder and the getter and setter which is the model

```
public class Ordering extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ViewHolder mAdapter;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private List<Model> mModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ordering);

        mRecyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mModel = new ArrayList<>();
        mDatabaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");
        mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Model model=postSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                    mModel.add(model);
                }
                mAdapter=new ViewHolder(Ordering.this, mModel);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(Ordering.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code works but it only shows this [recycler part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlKAp.png). I already did the database which looks like this [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcLZR.png). How do I show the images which have been stored in the database and show it in the recycler view? I'm still new in using firebase can someone help me, please?

This is my model.class @Alex
    public class Model {

```
String title,image,description; //These must be match in the firebase database

//Constructor
public Model()
{

}

//getter and setter


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: you can follow this answer to get your images from firebase :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622476/how-to-retrieve-images-from-firebase-storage-and-place-in-recycleview-android/55635926#55635926

Comment: @cutiko The problem is that I can't seem to load the image and description into the recycler view.

Comment: Please also add the content of your `Model` class and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I just edit my question the Model.class is above.

Comment: @SandeepMalik I tried it and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you getting the values of the other propertied `title` and `description`? Have you tried to comment `mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes. I have tried mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); but I am not getting any values from the title and description

Comment: Is your `onDataChange` even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo I think not because It just displays the layout of the recycler view.

Comment: Does `Toast.makeText(Ordering.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` toast something?

Comment: @AlexMamo None. It just displays the recycler view profile without the images and descriptions from my firebase.

Comment: If you try to print `mModelcur.getDescription()` inside your `onBindViewHolder` is anything printed? Are you also sure you have internet connection on your device?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yeah I am connected do you want to see my Logcat? It says here that in RecyclerView No adapter is attached

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677804/firebaserecycler-view-no-adater-attached-skipping-layout/54686007#54686007)** out.

Comment: @AlexMamo The no adpater has been fixed but the recycler view does not seem to change. I also found this on logcat is this a problem? No setter/field for image found on class com.example.firebaseproject.Model

Comment: I'll write you an answer right away.

Comment: @AlexMamo I still can't retrieve image from the database. I've been doing this since yesterday but so far no updates.

Comment: @JoshPool Have you seen my below answer, does it work?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yeah, I've tried it still can't retrieve the images and description from the database

Comment: @AlexMamo The description and title has changed but the Image is not.

Comment: So you can get now the `title` and the `description` but not the `image`, is that was it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> No setter/field for image found on class com.example.firebaseproject.Model

Because you are using in your `Model` class the fileds with no modifier. To solve this, change the modifier to `private`:

```
private String title, image, description;
```

Comment: It might be a problem with that `Picasso` library. Try using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    mRecyclerView.startListening()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    mRecyclerView.stopListening()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's look like the problem is from your image url use picasso 2.71828 and then you can see call back of image processing and you can see what is wrong there

```
Picasso.get().load(mModelcur.getImage()).into(imageViewHolder.image_view , new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Error e) {
            Log.i("log" , e.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used the latest version of picasso. Should I replace this picasso into the viewholder?

Comment: Yes , and then put log in on error method and read the exception

Comment: Log in and exception? Can you show me? I don't much understand what you mean sorry.

Comment: sure , I edit my code replace exaclly above code with your picasso code and then look for log message in your Logcat

Comment: Log.i method appears a log with "log" key in your Logcat bar if that's helpful

Comment: It isn't suppose to work it's only going to give you the problem

Comment: Can i see your mModelcur.getImage() value?

Comment: Is it this one? image_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rImageview); Sorry Im not sure of the names