# Trying to display an entire collection from my Firestore database using RecyclerView and Fragments - Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried many different tutorials and haven't been able to relate any to my application. My application in a gist displays a user's medication that they are taking. Here is my data class...

```
import java.util.HashMap

class LocalMedication {
    var m_medicationName: String? = null
    var m_medicationQty: String? = null
    var m_medicationType: String? = null
    var m_medicationExpDate: String? = null
    var m_medicationStatus: Boolean = false

    constructor() {}

    constructor(medicationName: String, medicationQty: String, medicationType: String, medicationExpDat : String, medicationStatus : Boolean) {
        this.m_medicationName = medicationName
        this.m_medicationType = medicationType
        this.m_medicationQty = medicationQty
        this.m_medicationExpDate = medicationExpDat
        this.m_medicationStatus = medicationStatus
    }

    fun toMap(): Map<String, Any> {

        val result = HashMap<String, Any>()
        result.put("medicationName", m_medicationName!!)
        result.put("medicationType", m_medicationType!!)
        result.put("medicationQty", m_medicationQty!!)
        result.put("medicationExpDate", m_medicationExpDate!!)
        result.put("medicationStatus", m_medicationStatus!!)

        return result
    }
}
```

Here is my view holder class

```
package com.example.home_med.viewHolder

import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.home_med.R

class medicationViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var medicationName: TextView
    var medicationType: TextView
    var medicationQty: TextView

    init {
        medicationName = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_medicationName)
        medicationType = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_medicationType)
        medicationQty = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_medicationQty)
    }
}
```

Here is my fragment

```
class LocalMedication : Fragment() {

    private var adapter: FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<LocalMedication, medicationViewHolder>? = null

    private var firestoreDB: FirebaseFirestore? = null
    private var firestoreListener: ListenerRegistration? = null
    private var medList = mutableListOf<LocalMedication>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        firestoreDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        val recyclerView = recyclerview as? RecyclerView

        val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
        recyclerView?.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()

        loadMedication()

        firestoreListener = firestoreDB!!.collection("notes")
            .addSnapshotListener(EventListener { documentSnapshots, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Listen failed!", e)
                    return@EventListener
                }

                medList = mutableListOf()

                if (documentSnapshots != null) {
                    for (doc in documentSnapshots) {
                        val note = doc.toObject(LocalMedication::class.java)
                        note.m_medicationName = doc.id
                        medList.add(note)
                    }
                }

                adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
            })
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        firestoreListener!!.remove()
    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding: FragmentLocalMedicationBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_local_medication, container, false)

        binding.viewMedicationButton.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
            v.findNavController().navigate(LocalMedicationDirections.actionLocalMedicationToViewMedication())
        }
        binding.addMedicationButton.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
            v.findNavController().navigate(LocalMedicationDirections.actionLocalMedicationToAddMedication())
        }
        binding.homeButton.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
            v.findNavController().navigate(LocalMedicationDirections.actionLocalMedicationToHome2())
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun loadMedication() {
        val query = firestoreDB!!.collection("notes")

        val response = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<LocalMedication>()
            .setQuery(query, LocalMedication::class.java)
            .build()

        adapter = object : FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<LocalMedication, medicationViewHolder>(response) {
            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: medicationViewHolder, position: Int, model: LocalMedication) {
                val note = medList[position]

                holder.medicationName.text = note.m_medicationName
                holder.medicationType.text = note.m_medicationType
                holder.medicationQty.text = note.m_medicationQty
            }

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): medicationViewHolder {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false)

                return medicationViewHolder(view)
            }

            override fun onError(e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
                Log.e("error", e!!.message)
            }
        }

        adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        recyclerview?.adapter = adapter
    }


    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        adapter!!.startListening()
    }

    public override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

        adapter!!.stopListening()
    }
}
```

Here is my recyclerViewItem XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rv_medicationName"
            style="@style/word_title"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rv_medicationQty"
            style="@style/word_title"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rv_medicationName"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rv_medicationType"
            style="@style/word_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rv_medicationQty"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my localMedications XML file

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".LocalMedication">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:text="LOCAL MEDICATION"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.478"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="543dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/homeButton"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/viewMedicationButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:text="View Med"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addMedicationButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:text="Add Medication"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/homeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="103dp"
            android:text="Home"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/viewMedicationButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/addMedicationButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addMedicationButton"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.972" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Here is what my database looks like...
[Datatbase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLP07.png)

Any help or guidance would be great. It runs the application, but in the Logs, it says "RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"

Comment: Are your items displayed? Please add your database structure as a screenshot and tell us what is wrong with your code.

Comment: The items are not displaying. I added a picture of how my database is structured.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that the names of the fields in your `LocalMedication` class are different than the name of the properties in your database. You have in your `LocalMedication` class a field named `m_medicationName` while in your database I see it as `medicationName` and this is **not** correct. The names must match. Behind the scene, Kotlin is creating a Java class with a getter named `getM_medicationName()` so Firebase is looking in the database for a field named `m_medicationName` and **not** `medicationName`.

There are two ways in which you can solve this problem. The first one would be to remove the data in your database and add it again using field names (`m_medicationName`, `m_medicationQty` etc) that exist in your `LocalMedication` class.

If you are not allowed to use the first solution, then the second approach will be to use `annotations` in front of your public fields. So you should use the [PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) annotation in front of every field. So in your `LocalMedication` class, a field should look like this:

```
@get:PropertyName("medicationName")
@set:PropertyName("medicationName")
public var m_medicationName: String? = null
```

As explained in my answer from the following post:

- [I am trying to get the correct reference to my Firebase Database child and set the values in my RecyclerView but I am having some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57882307/i-am-trying-to-get-the-correct-reference-to-my-firebase-database-child-and-set-t)

It's for Firebase realtime database but the same rules apply to Cloud Firestore.

Comment: I went ahead and changed my database fields to have the same name as my data class fields. No data is displaying still and I'm getting this message in the logs..."RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"

Comment: Without seeing your changed database and code, I cannot be much of a help. Besides that, that's only a warning caused by the fact that you [are setting the adapter in a background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677804/firebaserecycler-view-no-adater-attached-skipping-layout).