# Error in layout output:: RecyclerView: No Adapter attached; Skipping Layout

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Upon trying to load a "log viewer" I'm building, the original pre-set layout doesn't show as output. I do get the appropriate output from my Firebase database, but the layout is all messed up/way too spaced. What am I doing wrong?

This is my LogActivity Class
public class LogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
List<Log> log;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
LogAdapter logAdapter;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;


DatabaseReference mbase; // Create object of the
// Firebase Realtime Database

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log);
    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    log=new ArrayList<>();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Logs");

    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Log data = new Log(ds.getValue(String.class));
                log.add(data);
            }
            logAdapter = new LogAdapter(log);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(logAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

My Adapter Class is as shown below:
public class LogAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
List<Log> logList;

public LogAdapter(List<Log> logList) {
    this.logList = logList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.log_layout, parent,false);
    ViewHolderClass viewHolderClass = new ViewHolderClass(view);

    return viewHolderClass;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ViewHolderClass viewHolderClass=(ViewHolderClass)holder;
    Log log=logList.get(position);
    viewHolderClass.lockState.setText(log.getLockState());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return logList.size();
}

public class ViewHolderClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView lockState;


    public ViewHolderClass(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        lockState=itemView.findViewById(R.id.log_string);
    }
}
```

All of this interlocks with my " log" class which simply holds a string from my firebase DB

public class Log {

```
private String lockState;

public Log() {

}

public Log(String lockState) {
    this.lockState = lockState;
}

public String getLockState() {
    return lockState;
}

public void setLockState(String lockState) {
    this.lockState = lockState;
}
```

The following is the XML for my activity_log

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/cardBackground"
tools:context=".LogActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

XML for my log_layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/log_layout"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/log_string"
    android:text="20sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black">

</TextView>
```

Lastly here are the simple strings I'm fetching and displaying successfully:

[firebase-database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9nrt.png)

With my actual output here:
(scroll down and the next output is there)

[app-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoNOx.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: I've editted the question, hopefully it's more clear now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following **warning**, as it's not an Error nor an Exception:

```
Error in layout output:: RecyclerView: No Adapter attached; Skipping Layout
```

Because you are trying to read "Log" objects that don't exist in the "Logs" location in your database. If Log objects existed there, your database schema would have been looking like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- Logs
       |
       --- -MW6C...tJ_2
             |
             --- lockState: "14h01 - Connected - Locker is NOT empty"
```

Meaning that under the Logs node, you have a pushed key under which exists an object of type "Log". In your schema, you only have pushed keys that only hold some Strings, hence that warning. There are two solutions. The first is to change the schema as explained above, or to use an adapter class of type String, and  **not** `Log`.

Comment: thank you, i did as you suggested and I updated the hierarchy as you mentionned; yet my output still looks the same; every item is massively spaced out and not respecting the margins I set in my recycle/list view XML file. I'm also getting the same warning as previously; with the new schema

Comment: The "massively spaced out" is a layout problem, while the warning message that defines your question is "No Adapter attached; Skipping Layout", which is generated by another issue. However, that being said, you might also consider trying to [set the adapter outside the callback, and inside just notify the adapter about the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677804/firebaserecycler-view-no-adater-attached-skipping-layout/54686007#54686007).

Comment: thank you! fixed the warning error this way. props to you Alex

Comment: Good to hear that. You're very welcome, Tomasteel!