# error message: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Everything works fine but the data is not displayed.

But when I checked in "logcat" I this found this error messages:

> 2021-10-20 11:29:37.387 7327-7327/com.example.myplay E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

> 2021-10-20 11:29:37.388 7327-7327/com.example.myplay E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
    private List<DataModel> dataModels;
    private  SliderAdapter sliderAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Tech Videos");

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        SliderView sliderView = findViewById(R.id.sliderView);

        sliderAdapter  = new SliderAdapter(this);
        sliderView.setSliderAdapter(sliderAdapter);
        sliderView.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimationType.WORM);
        sliderView.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.SIMPLETRANSFORMATION);
        sliderView.setAutoCycleDirection(SliderView.AUTO_CYCLE_DIRECTION_BACK_AND_FORTH);
        sliderView.setIndicatorSelectedColor(Color.WHITE);
        sliderView.setIndicatorUnselectedColor(Color.GRAY);
        sliderView.setScrollTimeInSec(6);   // 6 sec is slider
        sliderView.setAutoCycle(true);
        sliderView.startAutoCycle();
        renewItems(sliderView);

        loadFirebaseForSlider();
    }

    private void loadFirebaseForSlider() {
        myRef.child("trailer").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot contentSlider: snapshot.getChildren()){

                    DataModel sliderItem = contentSlider.getValue(DataModel.class);
                    dataModels.add(sliderItem);
                }
                sliderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data can't fetch"+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadSliderAdapter(){
        sliderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void renewItems(View view) {
        dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
        DataModel dataItems = new DataModel();
        dataModels.add(dataItems);
        sliderAdapter.renewItems(dataModels);
        sliderAdapter.deleteItems(0);
    }
}
```

DataModel.java:

```js
package com.example.myplay;

public class DataModel {

    private String Ttitle;
    private String Turl;
    private String Tvid;

    public DataModel() {
    }

    public DataModel(String ttitle, String turl, String tvid){
        Ttitle = ttitle;
        Turl = turl;
        Tvid = tvid;
    }

    public String getTtitle() {
        return Ttitle;
    }

    public void setTtitle(String ttitle) {
        Ttitle = ttitle;
    }

    public String getTurl() {
        return Turl;
    }

    public void setTurl(String turl) {
        Turl = turl;
    }

    public String getTvid() {
        return Tvid;
    }

    public void setTvid(String tvid) {
        Tvid = tvid;
    }
}
```

SliderAdapter.java

```js
package com.example.myplay;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderViewAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SliderAdapter extends SliderViewAdapter<SliderAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

     private Context context;


    public SliderAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private List<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<>();

    public void renewItems(List<DataModel> dataModels){

        this.dataModels = dataModels;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void deleteItems(int position){
        this.dataModels.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {

      View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.slider_item,
              parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        viewHolder.trailer_title.setText(dataModels.get(position).getTtitle());
        Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView).load(dataModels.get(position).getTurl()).into(viewHolder.slider_image);
        viewHolder.play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent trailer_video = new Intent(context,PlayerActivity.class);
                trailer_video.putExtra("vid",dataModels.get(position).getTvid());
                trailer_video.putExtra("title",dataModels.get(position).getTtitle());
                v.getContext().startActivity(trailer_video);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataModels.size();
    }


     public  class MyViewHolder extends SliderViewAdapter.ViewHolder{
        ImageView slider_image;
        TextView trailer_title;
        FloatingActionButton play_button;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            slider_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_thumbnail);
            trailer_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.trailer_title);
            play_button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you setting the adapter? Most likely this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677804/firebaserecycler-view-no-adater-attached-skipping-layout/54686007#54686007) will help.

Comment: Adapter that i created named  "slideAdapter"

Answer (score 1):

As Alex commented, you're not yet telling the view to use the adapter you created, which means the view doesn't know anything about the adapter and its data.

To fix this, set the adapter to the view after initializing both of them in `onCreate`:

```
...
SliderView sliderView = findViewById(R.id.sliderView);

sliderAdapter  = new SliderAdapter(this);
...

sliderView.setAdapter(sliderAdapter); //
```

Comment: I upload more code can you check again plz

Comment: As far as I can see you're still not calling `setAdapter` anywhere. Did you try adding the line I marked in my answer to your own code?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work                                            sliderView.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);
error line "setAdapter"                                                                                                               and on Google i found this                                                                                                            ​setAdapter
(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)
in RecyclerView cannot be applied
to 
(example.example.com.project.ProductAdapter)